# Get input/output com port buffer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port, buffer

how can I read the current input/output buffer from a specific com port in C++ using the win API (windows.h)?

Is there a direct function for this?

I have found only [one function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-purgecomm) to clear the input/output buffers, but I dont want to clear the buffers. I want to get the buffers.

Edit:

To make it clearer what I intend to do.... I am aware that there is a function [ReadFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) with which I can read data from a given handle. Furthermore I know the function [WriteFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) to write data to a handle. But this is not what I would like to do... I want to read out the current input/output buffer of bytes which have not been read or sent yet. That is a difference!

See the documentation of this pyserial library... Especially the properties [`in_waiting`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.in_waiting) and [`out_waiting`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.out_waiting)

This is what I want to achieve and not just read... But thanks to the moderator who just closed this question.... Really great...

Comment: Have you noticed `hFile` and `CreateFile` in "See also"? Reading is just reading a file.

Comment: @273K Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I want to do. Furthermore, I also find it beautiful that the question already after a few minutes directly gets a downvote, without further comments... In addition, the question is closed with the reason that it has already been answered. I have modified the question to make my intentions clearer...

Comment: Use a not blocking file handle and `ReadFile()` will read data from a buffer if any.

Comment: Thats not what I want to do... I want to get the bytes that are available to read/write similar to the Serial().available() function on the Arduino.